# Transactional Email: What to put in Template Content

Tags: transactional-mail, contact-form

I have created a custom form, named careersForm.phtml. I have customized my fields. The problem is it does not send to the email because of different fields. I have found out that it should be done in Transactional Email. What should I put in it? I want a conditional statement if i use careers form, it should send Careers form field else, i should use the Contact form fields.

careersForm.phtml

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
<div class="page-title">
    <h1>Contact Us</h1>
</div>
<div id="messages_product_view"><?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?></div>
<div class="contact-main">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('additional_info')?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="row">
            <form action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('contacts/index/post'); ?>" id="careersForm" method="post">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 input-form">
                    <label>Position Applying *</label>
                    <input name="position-applying" id="position-applying" type="text" class="form-control form-control-2 required-entry" required />
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 input-form">
                    <label>First Name *</label>
                    <input name="first-name" id="first-name" type="text" class="form-control form-control-2 required-entry" required />
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 input-form">
                    <label>Last Name *</label>
                    <input name="last-name" id="last-name" type="text" class="form-control form-control-2 required-entry" required />
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 input-form">
                    <label>Contact Number *</label>
                    <input name="contact-number" id="contact-number" type="text" class="form-control form-control-2 required-entry" pattern="^[0-9]+$" title="Input number only!" required />
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 input-form">
                    <label>Email *</label>
                    <input name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->helper('contacts')->getUserEmail()) ?>" class="required-entry validate-email form-control form-control-1" type="text" required />
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 input-form">
                    <label>Address *</label>
                    <textarea name="address" id="address" class="form-control form-control-2 required-entry" required></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 input-form">
                    <label>Upload Resume * </label>
                    <input type="file" name="upload-resume" id="upload-resume" class="required-entry" required>
                </div>
                <div class="buttons-set col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 input-form">
                    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Le25T0UAAAAAL-AId-KUn4rrW3eRHfR1HaYaVfg"></div>
                    <div>* Required Fields</div>
                    <input type="text" name="hideit" id="hideit" value="" style="display:none !important;" />
                    <button type="submit" class="button btn btn-primary btn-sm"><span><span><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Submit') ?><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i></span></span></button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <?php 
            if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
                echo "FORM SUCCESSFULLY SUBMITTED";
            }
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
            var contactForm = new VarienForm('contactForm', true);
        //]]>
        </script>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
```